# Name of first file in directory obtained in optimal way

Tags: command-line, files, filesystem, ls

Ordinary when I want to show name of first file from directory I type:

```
ls raw/all | head -n 1
```

But it takes long time when in directory there any many files

---

Eg for dir with near to 900 k files we have following measurements:

```
time ls raw/all | head -n 1 

real    0m17.250s | 0m10.328s | 0m6.334s
user    0m3.224s  | 0m3.884s  | 0m3.192s
sys     0m0.544s  | 0m0.664s  | 0m0.572s
```

while loop over all files takes:

```
time ls raw/all | wc -l

real    0m6.455s | 0m5.869s  | 0m5.228s
user    0m3.612s | 0m3.468s  | 0m4.072s
sys     0m0.460s | 0m0.784s  | 0m0.624s
```

How print name of first file in **efficient** way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky. Two approaches:

---

**Approach 1; `find`:**

```
find . -mindepth 1 -print -quit
```

`find` and `-print`s the first file found, and `-quit`s immediately. `-mindepth 1` would prevent matching the `.` hardlink of the current directory.

If you are interested in regular files only, add `-type f`:

```
find . -type f  -print -quit
```

`-mindepth 1` can be dropped then as the `.` being a directory would not be matched.

---

**Approach 2; `sh`, `stdbuf`, and `awk`:**

*Note that, this might suffer from `ARG_MAX` being triggered for too many files (argument list becoming too long, over `ARG_MAX` bytes). In that case, use approach 1.*

- any shell builin (e.g. `printf`, `echo`) to print the filename
- shell globbing, `*`, to do the expansion (the collation order should be the same as `ls` for  a given `locale`'s `LC_COLLATE`)
- `stdbuf -o0` (`stdbuf` comes with GNU `coreutils`) to make the STDOUT stream of `printf`/`echo` unbuffered
- pipe (`|`) the STDOUT of `printf`/`echo` to `awk` and `exit` after printing the first record
- After `awk` exits, `stdbuf` (`printf`) would receive `SIGPIPE`, and would be killed
- I would use `printf` to get the filenames separated by ASCII NUL (`\0`), and use `\0` as the record separator in `awk` to tackle any edge cases as far as the filenames are concerned

Putting these together:

```
stdbuf -o0 printf '%s\0' * | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} {print;  exit}'
```

Comment: Looks awesome but: stdbuf -o0 printf '%s\0' raw/all/* | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} {print;  exit}' first froozen my terminal, but on catalog with 200k files prints: `bash: /usr/bin/stdbuf: List of arguments too long`. So if it is impossible to get first file due to sorting, we can change question: "How to get any filename, not necessary first?"

Comment: @Daniel Ahhh, `ARG_MAX` is being triggered. Does `find . -mindepth 1 -print -quit` work? Prepend `stdbuf -o0` as well...

Comment: Yes. Please update your answer and explain why We want to have `unbuffored` stream? It works with and without stdbuf -o0.

Comment: @Daniel Updated. `stdbuf -o0` is not needed here because `find` is quitting immediately, no chance of storing in buffer and flushing later.